# DL4J. After doing model.upgrade(Gradient) are the weights updated?

Tags: machine-learning, deeplearning4j

I am using a `MultiLayerNetwork`. This network is trained and the results are as expected.
As part of an effort to implement `Federated Learning` I need to upgrade the weights of this network with a new set of gradients coming from an external component.

My question is, in DL4J, once you execute `model.update(newGradients)`, are the weights updated too or do I need to execute something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the answer to my question.

After updating the gradient, you have to update the weights (params)

If using an SGD, you would do something like this:

```
model.update(averageGradient);
INDArray params = model.params(true);
params.addi(averageGradient.gradient());
```

I hope it helps anyone else with a similar problem!